# OpenGL 3.2 Color GL_TRIANGLES

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opengl

I'm currently trying to make a very simple snake game and have some problem creating the snake square. Right now I am creating the squares by creating 2 triangles. I have created the grid where the snake should be moving like this:
[image]

The color of the squares were actually yellow in the beginning. Then I tried to create the snake with the color red. But all my squares turned red.

I create the snake like this:

```
void drawSnake()
{
    mat4 modelView;

    modelView = Translate(1,0,0);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelViewUniform, 1, GL_TRUE, modelView);
    GLuint indices2[3] = {0,1,2}; //, 0, 5, 1, 0};

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices2);

    modelView = Translate(1, 0, 0);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelViewUniform, 1, GL_TRUE, modelView);
    GLuint indices6[3] = {4,3,2}; //, 0, 5, 1, 0};
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices6);
    //vec2 blockCoordinate = vec2(-t + 1, t - 1);
    //blockCol[i] = blockCoordinate;
}
```

The colors defined here:

```
void loadGeometry() {
    vec3 color(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    Vertex rectangleData[rectangleSize] = {
        { vec2( -1.0, -1.0 ), color },
        { vec2( 1.0, -1.0 ), color },
        { vec2( 1.0,  1.0 ), color },
        { vec2( -1.0,  1.0 ), color },
        { vec2(-1.0, -1.0 ), color }
    };
    shapeVertexArrayBuffer = loadBufferData(rectangleData, rectangleSize);

    vec3 color1(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    Vertex rectangleData1[rectangleSize] = {
        { vec2( -1.0, -1.0 ), color1 },
        { vec2( 1.0, -1.0 ), color1 },
        { vec2( 1.0,  1.0 ), color1 },
        { vec2( -1.0,  1.0 ), color1 },
        { vec2(-1.0, -1.0 ), color1 }
    };
    shapeSnakeArrayBuffer = loadBufferData(rectangleData1, rectangleSize);
}
```

So the question is why all my squares turned red when I obviously load the buffer data with another color?

I draw them like this in the display():

```
void display() {    
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

    mat4 projection = Ortho2D(-15.0f, 15.0f, -15.0f, 15.0f);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionUniform, 1, GL_TRUE, projection);

    glBindVertexArray(shapeVertexArrayBuffer);
    glBindVertexArray(shapeSnakeArrayBuffer);

    drawBlock();
    drawSnake();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: I added a question in the end sorry.

Comment: How are you drawing the rectangles?

Comment: I draw them in the display function. I edited the original post.

Comment: What about this mysterious "loadBufferData" function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
glBindVertexArray(shapeVertexArrayBuffer);
glBindVertexArray(shapeSnakeArrayBuffer);

drawBlock();
drawSnake();
```

You seem to have some ordering problems here. Presumably the `shapeVertexArrayBuffer` (note: there's no such thing as a "vertex array buffer". Those are supposed to be [vertex array objects](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object); if `loadBufferData` doesn't return a VAO, then you have more problems) is meant for drawing blocks, and the `shapeSnakeArrayBuffer` is meant for drawing the snake.

You can only have one VAO active at a time. `glBindVertexArray` sets the given vertex array object to be what is used for all rendering commands after it. Since the last one you used was `shapeSnakeArrayBuffer`, that will be the VAO used for all rendering commands in `drawBlock` just as well as for `drawSnake`.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you do:

```
glBindVertexArray(shapeVertexArrayBuffer);
drawBlock();

glBindVertexArray(shapeSnakeArrayBuffer);
drawSnake();
```